# Only show validation messages on submit with HTML5. Prevent recheck

Tags: html, forms, validation

On HTML5 validation if you submit the form the validation errors appears and if you edit the input while the message is shown it keeps validating the input. I would like to prevent this from happening...only change the message if form is submitted again. Demo:

[image]

Code:

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```